# How to auto-generate constructors with ReSharper for many classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

How to generate constructors with ReSharper for many selected classes?

I'm working with **VS2010 + ReSharper 8.1**.

Inside one file I've created many (empty)classes:

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C { }
...
```

All of them should have a constructor with the the same signature like this:

```
class A { internal A(int x) { } }
class B { internal B(int x) { } }
class C { internal C(int x) { } }
...
```

I know how to generate a constructor for a single class by pressing `ALT+INS` to select `Constructor`, but this generates the parameter-less standard constructor and I have to repeat the procedure for every class manually.

**So my question is, if there is a way to auto-generate code like the second snippet from the first.**

*Edit 1: I created a quick and dirty solution, which made it, but maybe any of you knows an automatic way :-)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "Find and Replace" function with regular expressions I created a quick and dirty solution:

Find what: `{class }{[a-zA-Z]+}{[\n ]*\{}`

Replace with: `\1\2\3\ninternal \2(int x){}`